# Any alternative to constraints?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am having trouble with constraints is there other way besides constraints and if yes what is it?

I have already tired constraint but its difficult and complex.

Comment: Well, I guess thats just part of programming, it's difficult and complex when you don't know how. But yes, you can calculate the bounds and act upon that to place your views. But even with constraints, you can do it by using the storyboard or programmatically. Try looking up visual language format, could save you a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: no,there isn't any alternatives.but you may help if you try to use `stack views`.but for that also you should have some basic knowledge of constraints.but not much.But I suggest you to start learn `autolayout`, it is pretty nice concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no easier alternative to constraints if you want to use storyboard. They can be pretty tough to get down and I had trouble with them myself when I started out. Here is a tutorial that helped me personally. [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)

Comment: Actually, you can disable the auto layout engine, and frame the views from code.

Comment: @Cristik I definitely meant easier alternative. AutoLayout is arguably the best way to go about things for simplicity. It won't be less difficult or less complex to code everything up, which is what this person was asking for.

Comment: Also, while disabling AutoLayout might make it easier to set up a view for one screen size, it will make it much harder and more complex to cater for the full range of sizes that any modern iOS app needs to deal with, unless the user is prepared to compromise their UI quality by enabling screen scaling

Answer (score 1):

You can opt out of using constraints by disabling AutoLayout. Please note that in this case you will have to manually adjust your subviews, via autoresizing masks and the `layoutSubviews` method, which translates in more code to write, that can be tedious and error-prone when dealing with many views.

Disabling AutoLayout can be done from `Inspector->File Inspector->Interface Builder Document`.

[image: disable autolayout image]